# Display inputted constant on MsgBox

Tags: vba, excel

I have to perform this assignment and my code is not working. My biggest problem is being able to display, on the critical error pop up box, the inputted "constant" that I receive from the user if it is not a number.

**Step 1**:  Gather Inputs and Validate Numbers
Write a macro that asks how many people are coming to your party and assign the input to a variable. Next, the macro will ask how many slices of pizza each person will eat and assign the input to a new variable. Finally, the macro will ask how many slices of pizza will be ordered and assign the input to a new variable. If any of the inputs is not a number (Hint: use `IsNumeric()` function to check) , have a message pop up with a critical sign indicating that the input was invalid.

**Step 2**:  Calculation and Give Feedback
If all three inputs are valid, perform a calculation to decide if enough slices have been ordered.  If yes, have a message box pop up which indicates the number of slices ordered, the amount each person can eat, and how many slices will be left over. If not, have a message box pop up indicating that ordered amount of slices wasn't enough and how many more slices you will need to order.

```
Sub HW_3_1()

    Dim people As String
    Dim slicesperperson As String
    Dim numberofslices As Integer

    people = InputBox("How many people are coming to the Pizza party?")

    If IsNumeric(people) = False Then
        yess = MsgBox(people & "It is not a number please try again", vbCritical)
    End If

    slices = InputBox("How many slices per person? ")
    If IsNumeric(slices) = False Then
        yes = MsgBox(slices & "It is not a number please try again", vbCritical)
    End If


    Order = InputBox("How many slices will you order? ")
    If IsNumeric(Order) = False Then
        yes = MsgBox(Order & "It is not a number please try again", vbCritical)
    End If

    numberofslices = people * slices
    If Order < numberofslices Then
        yessss = MsgBox("That is not enough slices of pizza please try again", vbCritical)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The input value shows in the message box. But you may want to use an additional space in the message, just after the opening quote character, so the input value is easier to read.

Comment: Firstly, as you need the user to enter multiple values, there are better options then an `InputBox` (i.e. have a `UserForm` collect the values or have the user enter the data in cells and have a button to calculate the values). If you really want to use `InputBox`, use `Application.InputBox`. i.e. **`iPeople = Application.InputBox("How many people are coming to the Pizza party?", Type:=1)`**. This will limit the user to only enter a number (where `iPeople` is of type `Long` and `Type:=1` is to limit the user only to enter a numeric value)